# check convergence of sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I want to show if the following sequences are pointwise convergent and if uniformly convergent.

a)  $f_n(x)$ =

- $(-1)^n\: if\:x\in [0,\frac1n]$
- $0 \: if\:x\in (\frac1n,1]$. Over [0,1],

b) $f_n(x)$=

- $0\: if\: x=0\: or\:x\in (\frac1n,1]$
- $(-1)^n n \:if\: x \in (0,\frac1n]$. Over [0,1],

Here's what I've done, I'm not sure if I'm doing it right:

a)If $x\in[0,1]$, then $f_n(x) = (-1)^n$ for all $n\leq1/x$. $f_n(x)=0\rightarrow0$ for all $n>1/x$. Since $(-1)^n$ doesn't converge then $f_n$ is not pontwise convergent.

b) If $x\in (0,1]$, then $f_n(x)=0 \rightarrow0$ for all $n>1/x$. and   $f_n(x)=(-1)^nn$ for all $n\leq1/x$ which doesn't converge pointwise also f(0) = 0.

I'm not sure if the convergences are correct?

Comment: there's sort of a lot going on here and the formatting is difficult to read. Might be worth splitting this up into a few separate questions

Comment: took the big one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your answer in part a) is correct, but it's hard to follow what you're saying.  I would rephrase the answer something like

a) If $0<x\le 1,$ then $f_n(x) = 0$ when $n > 1/x,$ so $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0.$  However, $f_n(0) = \pm 1$ for all $n,$ so $f_n$ does not converge at $x=0.$

Now in b) your answer is incorrect, and I can't help thinking it's mainly because you aren't expressing your ideas clearly, so you're getting confused.

It's the same idea; when $n >1/x, f_n(x) = 0,$ so $f_n(x) \rightarrow 0.$  However, this time we also have $f_n(0) \rightarrow 0$  The statement you make just seems to assert the the sequence doesn't converge without any support, but it's hard for me to be sure.  I don't know if the beginning of your answer is just restating the question, or if there's supposed to be some reasoning there that I'm missing.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my bad expression. I'm confused in part (b) in the case  when $n\leq1/x$. In this case $f_n(x) = (-1)^nn$, which doesn't converge right?

Comment: We have $f_n(x) = 0$ when $1/n<x,$ which is to say, when $n>1/x.$   Take another look: $f_n(x) = 0$ when $x\in (1/n, 1].$  That is to say, when $1/n < x \le 1.$   You need to fix $x$ and look at what happens when $n$ gets large.  You might try graphing $f_k$ for some small values of $k$.